# Display of hierarchical Taxonomy in views along with the related content

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a Hierarchical Taxonomy like:

> Bachelor of Degree
>   -Year1(child term of Bachelor of Degree)
>   --Term1(child term of Year1)
>   -Year2
>   --Term2
>
> etc etc...

The contents content1, content2... of a Content type will go under Terms Term1, Term2...

Can you kindly help me in getting the view as:

> Bachelor of Degree
>   -Year1(child term of Bachelor of Degree)
>   --Term1(child term of Year1)
>        content1
>        content3
>   -Year2
>   --Term2
>        content2
>        content4

Answer (score 0):

1-
Use [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. it may help you.

2- by using the [Taxonomy menu](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu/) module

3- use [Views Tree](http://drupal.org/project/views_tree) and [Views Field View](http://drupal.org/project/views_field_view)